# How do you set multiple strings in XSL?

Tags: xml, string, xslt

This is a condition that I am using on an XSL file that I have:

```
<xsl:when test="@Group = 'Books'">
    <tr style="background:#EBEBEB;">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Group"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Start"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:when test="@Group = 'Movies'">
    <tr style="background:#EBEBEB;">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Group"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Start"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:when>
```

I want to merge this code into something smaller, because basically these two boxes say the same. Maybe something like this:(?)

```
<xsl:when test="@Group = 'Movies' or @Group = 'Books'">
```

How do you set multiple strings in one place together?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `@Group = 'Movies' or @Group = 'Books'` is a valid expression. What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need some parentheses

```
<xsl:when test="(@Group = 'Movies') or (@Group = 'Books')">
```

Comment: I agree with Kiril - this should be valid '<xsl:when test="@Group = 'Movies' or @Group = 'Books'">' Could you post the input XML and the actual XSLT not just a snippet as I suspect the issue isn't with the snippet?

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 you may write the shorter condition. This is helpful if you have several possible values:

```
<xsl:when test="@Group = ('Movies', 'Books')">
```